# I can't connect to network in Scientific linux 6.9

Tags: rhel, wifi, networkmanager, scientific-linux, surface

I installed scientific linux 6.9(based on redhat 6 ) on my surface book but it  doesn't connect to my wireless network . When I open system preferences + network , it doesn't find any existing wireless and when I manually add a new network connection, it never connects to it . What should I do ?

`lspci` output is :

```
[fatemeh@localhost ~]$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers 
(rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
00:05.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Imaging Unit (rev 01)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:14.3 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d32 (rev 01) 
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:15.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #2 (rev 21)
00:15.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #3 (rev 21) 
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:16.4 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3e (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1b (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88W8897 [AVASTAR] 802.11ac Wireless
```

`lsusb` output is :

```
[fatemeh@localhost ~]$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:091a Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045e:090b Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:07cd Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
```

[image: When i went to System Preferences + Network Connections it showed this window without any connction then i added nargess connection. When i connect my modem via usb it doesn't show any wired connection.]

Comment: Perhaps you need to install drivers for the WiFi? It depends on which device you have. Please [edit] and post that information. It should be listed with `lspci` if internal or with `lsusb` if it's a USB dongle.

Comment: You will be best served, and you will best help others by your experience by asking this question at https://scientificlinuxforum.org/ They are most likely to have people who have gone through the same trouble and know **exactly** which package and driver to install, and what other special problems might exist in that particular linux distribution.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo modprobe -v mwifiex_pcie` ? if you get an error , the `mwifiex_pcie` can be loaded after installing the `kmod-compat-wireless` package see here https://centos.pkgs.org/6/elrepo-x86_64/kmod-compat-wireless-3.3-2.n.el6.elrepo.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: thank you @ user1404316. I comment on scientificlinuxforum.org  but no one has answered yet.

Comment: unfortunately I can not install because i can not connect to internet in SL.